# Add CSS positioning to buttons

Tags: css

I have a previous and a next button for a php pagination script, which both fall under the class paginate.

```
.paginate {
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   padding: 3px;
   width:400px;
}

.paginate a {
   padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;
   margin:2px;
   text-decoration:none;
   color: #fff;
   width: 180px;
}
```

so i have given them both their own individual classes Next and previous

Next

```
.next {
   background: url("../images/more.fw.png") no-repeat;
   height: 87px;
   width:128px;
   padding:10px;
   margin:50px;
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:24px;
   color:#fff;
   position:fixed;
   top:585px;
   right:470px;
}
```

Previous

```
.previous {
   background: url("../images/previous.fw.png") no-repeat;
   height: 87px;
   width:128px;
   padding:10px;
   margin:50px;
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:24px;
   color:#fff;
   position:fixed;
   top:585px;
   right:620px;
}
```

As you can see in the link below these buttons fit perfectly side by side when set against the top of the page, however what i am trying to do is get the buttons to sit say 20 px below the section above.  However if i change ti from top 558px, what happens is the buttons sit at different heights and will not sit next to one another.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have the style set to `position: fixed`, so they wont move when the screen scrolls - is this what you want?

```
.paginate {
    position: relative;
    ...

.next {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    ...
```

Now set your button `top` and `right` all relative to the paginate container

Comment: Thanks when i remove the position fixed, the buttons end up looking like this:  http://www.qrrw.net/E

Comment: Your html is pretty broken there - you have the next button inside the previous button!

Comment: Thanks no that doesn't work, nothing seems to does apart what i put the first time http://www.qrrw.net/E  i think the problem must be because both buttons are in the same class

Comment: Mate nothing is going to work properly until you fix your html up, you still have the next button div inside the previous button div. How is that going to work?

Comment: Look at the state of it: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.automoboil.com%2Fmanufacturer.php%3Ffuel_type%3DPetrol&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: thanks it's the php i will have to re write it all cherrs, though

Answer (score 0):

you can set the button by  `position:absolute;` on both the .next and .previous so that the potion of button wont change